# Vuejs with vue-cli: Error when running "npm run dev"

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, centos, vue.js

My environment:

- Centos7 on VirtualBox (true OS : Windows 7)
- Node version: 6.10.3
- Npm version : 3.10.10
- **I'm behind a corporate proxy**

I installed vue-cli, like this:

```
sudo npm install -g vue-cli
```

Then I initialized a new project "vuetest", like this:

```
vue init webpack-simple vuetest
```

Then I ran this command in the "vuetest" folder:

```
sudo npm install
```

But now, I get an error when running "npm run dev". The error:

```
> vuetest@1.0.0 dev /var/www/html/vuetest
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn webpack-dev-server ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:505:3

npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! vuetest@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vuetest@1.0.0 dev script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the vuetest package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs vuetest
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls vuetest
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/html/vuetest/npm-debug.log
```

EDIT : here's the contents of the "npm-debug.log" file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.10.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle vuetest@1.0.0~predev: vuetest@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle vuetest@1.0.0~predev: no script for predev, continuing
7 info lifecycle vuetest@1.0.0~dev: vuetest@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle vuetest@1.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle vuetest@1.0.0~dev: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/html/vuetest/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/bdupre/.local/bin:/home/bdupre/bin
10 verbose lifecycle vuetest@1.0.0~dev: CWD: /var/www/html/vuetest
11 silly lifecycle vuetest@1.0.0~dev: Args: [ '-c',
11 silly lifecycle   'cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot' ]
12 silly lifecycle vuetest@1.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle vuetest@1.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
14 verbose stack Error: vuetest@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:255:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid vuetest@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd /var/www/html/vuetest
17 error Linux 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
18 error argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
19 error node v6.10.3
20 error npm  v3.10.10
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error vuetest@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the vuetest@1.0.0 dev script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the vuetest package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs vuetest
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls vuetest
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Does anyone know how to fix it please?

Comment: What are the permissions associated with that directory?

Comment: I just run "ls -ld vuetest".
Result : drwxrwxrwx

Comment: If the below helped can you mark this as the answer?

Comment: It didn't help at the moment. What am I supposed to do with this information?

Comment: Worries me there's no answer to this question yet. Is the Vue.js community really this small?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following navigate into the vuetest directory and first

```
npm install
```

then run `npm run dev`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried your solution, but unfortunately after that I still have the same error.